# JMESPath multiple filters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

I want to get instances with a tag that has a value.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query \
'Reservations[].Instances[? Tags[?Key==`datadog` && Value==`true`] ].Tags'
```

However I'm not getting my results this way.
If I remove the `&& Value=='true'` I'm getting the instances with `datadog = true` and `datadog = false`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter values, it is easier to use `--filter` than to try and code it into the `--query`.

From [describe-instances — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html):

> To describe all instances with a Purpose=test tag
>
> ```
> aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Purpose,Values=test"
> ```

So you would use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:datadog,Values=true"
```

Comment: This is not an answer. The question was not "what other alternative should I have used", it was "how do I do this with JMESPath". Back to Google for me...